# Can my friend buy a car in gta 5 and mod it and give it to me if he removed the cars insurance so I can keep it

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want the car but I don't have a lot of money to mod it. My friend does. Can he give it to me after modding so I can keep it for myself?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to give a player a car that you modded  (at least it was not sure as of now) is if it was found on the streets, upgraded by one player then given to another without the insurance attached. Otherwise, it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The awnser is: No. You cannot get a car that is bought by an another player. You will only get a message that you cant put it on your garage beacuse a player owns it.